# Rounding in a rails number_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, input, display

I have a number_field thus:

```
<%= ff.number_field :total_cost_savings, {class: 'form-control number', :step => 0.01} %>
```

I enter the value 1.1, save and refresh and it displays the value "1.100000023841858".  I understand that this is because the underlying database field is a float and that I could change the database field to be a decimal, but isn't there some way to control the display formatting of the number_field instead?

Comment: You would like to have a look on https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
<%= ff.number_field :total_cost_savings, {value: number_with_precision(ff.object.total_cost_savings, precision: 2), class: 'form-control number', :step => 0.01} %>
```

Comment: Petro's answer is also good but is a little more complex than I wanted.

Comment: Based on Ray's comment I changed from round to [number_with_precision](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision).  This has the added advantage of dealing with nil values properly.

Answer (score 0):

For prices you can do like this:

```
    f.number_field :total_cost_savings, value: number_to_currency(f.object.total_cost_savings, delimiter: '', unit: ''), step: 0.01
```

Also, you can overwrite the active record getter, by adding this to your model file:

```
    def total_cost_savings
      read_attribute(:total_cost_savings).round(2)
    end
```